# Electric field of an ring of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

I am told that I have a ring of charge, I am given the radius, and I am told my non uniform linear charge density ( in nC/m), I want to find the electric field given a distance I am above the center.

How exactly would I calculate the electric field? I found the formula online for electric fields with uniform charge density, but can't find anything with non uniform charge density.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

calculate centre of  charge by the process of integration and then find potential and fields.

Comment: Could you give more details on how to set up the problem?

Comment: +1; the best answer to any homework-question! However you could elaborate more to explain things to OP:)